# DZ.getLoginStatus can't get data and throw error

Tags: javascript, deezer

I use premium Dezeer account to authorize my app run in localhost. After sucessfully authorize app, I call DZ.getLoginStatus and it throw error in console:

> Refused to display
>   'https://connect.deezer.com/oauth/auth.php?app_id=my_app_id&format=channel&redirect_uri=http://localhost/tracks&response_type=token'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Any folks know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the channelUrl is set to a bad value during initialization:

```
DZ.init({
    appId: "myAppId",
    channelUrl : "http://badUrlPrefix/deezer-channel.html",
    player: {
        // ...
    },
});
```